# Which is better for a wordpress plugin? Query a separate database from wordpress, or create a cross database view in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have some data in another database which is separate from the wordpress database on my mysql installation.

I've heard that it can be a little tricky to get data from a different database as wordpress assumes you'll just want wordpress data.

Since it's just one table, can I get by with just creating a cross database view in the wordpress database?  Are there performance considerations to think about?

Answer (score 0):

I would just give permission through mysql to allow your wordpress database user to access the other table. This will work fine.

Two databases:

```
DB1
Table1
Table2

DB2
Table3
Table4
```

Then all you do is something like this:

```
select * from  DB1.table1, DB2,table3 where DB1.field1 = DB2.field1
```

Hope that makes sense :)